# R ggplot geom_tile without fill color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a geom_tile layer to a plot without the filled color (just the outline). Is there a way to get a transparent tile where only the boundary is visible?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried?  if you post a sample of your code you're more likely to get a specific answer rather than a general one like "yes there is."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I *think* you are after `alpha` parameter. Minimal example:

1. Create a plot with dummy data where you set `color` (for "boundary") and no `fill`:

   ```
   p <- ggplot(pp(20)[sample(20*20, size=200), ], aes(x = x, y = y, color = z))
   ```
2. Add `geom_tile()` with `alpha` set to `zero`:

   ```
   p <- geom_tile(alpha=0)
   ```
3. Add `theme_bw()` as transparent tiles look lame with a dark gray background :)

   ```
   p + theme_bw()
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you only want the outlines as a single colour you can set `fill = NA`, and then set the `na.value` to `NA`

```
.data <- cbind( 
           expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 1:10), z = runif(100))[sample(1:100,75), ]



ggplot(.data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + theme_bw() + 
   geom_tile(fill = NA, color = 'black', na.value = NA)
```